# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<directory>''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to import a file from subdir and I get an error like that:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'special'

```
│   
├── constants.py
├── crawler.py
├── case.py ===================>>>> I working on this file
├── special
    ├── __init__.py
    └── wantToImport.py =================>>>I want to import this file
```

My case.py like that:

```
from special.wantToImport import ImportClass
```

And my wantToImport.py file like that:

```
class ImportClass:

    def mydefination(self):
        #Some codes here
```

I want to use mydefinitioon function on my case.py file But I cannot import this file.
Why Im getting this error?
How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You should tell Python that your module's path is inside the current directory (using a `.`):

```
from .special.wantToImport import ImportClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `__init__.py` file in the directory where you are working and use it to refer your module.

```
│
root   
├── constants.py
├── crawler.py
├── case.py ===================>>>> I working on this file
├── __init__.py
├── special
    ├── __init__.py
    └── wantToImport.py =================>>>I want to import this file
```

inport it using

```
from root.special.wantToImport import ImportClass
```